# Can't access to json values into ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a EJS template where i want to use my json data.

My json look like:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File"
  },
  "menu2": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File"
  }
}
```

After i export my json in my nodejs app to be able to use this json everywhere because it will be in my navbar:

```
const navigation = require('./templates/partials/header/navigation.json');


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    app.locals = {
        navigation: navigation
    };
....
});
```

And I use my use my data in my partial:

```
<%for(let el in navigation){%>
console.log(el) //return 'menu1' & 'menu2'
console.log(el.id) //return undefined & undefined
<%}%>
```

The problem is the second console.log, it return undefined values I don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(el["id"])` ?

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Plain objects don't have iterators, you can't use `for-of` on them directly. (See my answer for what you can do instead.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`el` is a **string**, not the object. `for-in` loops through the property names in the object, not their values. To access the *value* of the property using a `for-in` loop, you'd have to use the `el` via brackets notation (`navigation[el]`):

```
<%for(let el in navigation){%>
console.log(navigation[el].id)
<%}%>
```

But in any modern environment, you could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead, if you don't need the property names:

```
<%for(let el of Object.values(navigation)){%>
console.log(el.id)
<%}%>
```

If you need the property names, either continue using `for-in` (but correctly), or use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), perhaps with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
<%for(let [name, value] of Object.entries(navigation)){%>
console.log(name, value.id)
<%}%>
```

Comment: <%for(let el of Object.values(navigation)){%>
What i was waiting for perfect thank you . 

Answer (score 0):

additionally with express, if you declare a local variable you can access from any part of your controller using the req object

```
const navigation = require('./templates/partials/header/navigation.json');

   app.locals.navigation = navigation;

   router.get("/your_route", function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).json(req.app.locals.navigation)
   })
```

and You can also pass it as a property,

```
   router.get("/your_route", function(req, res, next) {
      res.render("your_template_name", {
       navigation:req.app.locals.navigation
      });
   })

  <ul
     <% navigation.forEach(function(el) { %>
     <li><%= el.value %></li> 
     <% }); %>
  </ul>
```